# Java LibGdx - When in pause, how do I resume what I was doing before?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have created a simple pause menu, and when I want to go back to the game screen I click resume and it obviously doesnt load anything because Im guessing it didnt save any values before when it paused. I was wondering how to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same troubles. And after pause libgdx call dispose. And then create everething again. I think you can save necessary data to sharedpreferences and then check if some saved there recover game by hand. Don't sure it's better way.

Comment: I thought of doing that, but would that not just restart the game essentially?

Answer (score 0):

A way to make this work, is declaring your game data public and static, things such as players class, enemys, or whatever you use in your game, this is not probably the best ideea..

The best way to do this, is making an enum like GameState

```
   public enum GameState
  {
      Playing,Paused,Over;
  }
  GameState state;
```

Now make a class that will be your pause screen, but don't implement the Screen class, just add your textures or whatever more you need and add a Draw Method and maybe update if you also need it.
And in your Game Screen declare it.

```
PauseMenu pauseMenu=new PauseMenu();
```

And in the render method of your game screen check for the game states

```
   if(state==GameState.Paused)
       {
        pauseMenu.Draw(batch);
       }
    if(state==GameState.Playing)
      {
// here you draw everything you want for the game while is playing
      }
```

And don't forget to not update the game objects if your GameState is GameState.Playing.

Comment: How do I draw the stuff for while its playing? Most of my stuff is in the show() method, and the map is randomly generated, so if I call that again will it not re generate my map? How does it know where all my stuff was before?